# How to cache asset files when batch creating thousands of PDFs using wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

We are using the excellent [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to render PDFs from HTML web pages on our website.  We need to render and store about 10,000 PDFs in a single batch job.  This poses a problem.

Gathering the JS, CSS and image assets required for every PDF via HTTP is going to be very slow - is there a way to cache the files like a browser does across each request ?  wkhtmltopdf doesn't seem to have any options to do this when batch creating PDFs.

Comment: Just an idea... How about generating all the PDFs together as one giant 10,000-document PDF? That way `wkhtmltopdf` has to load assets once. Afterwards, you can split the huge PDF into individual components with the [PDFtk toolkit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).